# What is the type of noise in this image?

Tags: noise, image-processing, frequency-domain

what reason could make the noise/effect in this image?
[image: noisy image]
Below is the original
[image: original]
Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. It looks like a texture was superimposed on the image. Nothing distinctive pops up in the spectra. Wild guess, if it was a process: fractional Wiener sheets.

Comment: I think certain phase components have been missing/removed in the frequency domain.

Comment: SE.DSP wishes you a happy new year 2017, with a kind reminder that your question and its answers may require some action (update, votes, acceptance, etc.)

Comment: Your question has beeen answered. Do not hesitate to vote for the useful ones and accept the most suitable

Answer (score 2):

Looking at it, my thought is that the top image has been printed out (onto poor quality paper), then later scanned.  The artefacts would then be a mixture of paper texture and poor printing.  It could also include ink transfer from the facing page (if part of a book or newspaper, and/or bleed-through from something printed on the back of the paper.

Answer (score 1):

If you crop the distorted image to remove the white border, you get an image with an aspect ratio of $1:1.5$ ($512\times683$ instead of  $768\times1024$). So you have **undersampling noise**, potentially aliasing, because a proper resampling should have smoothly interpolated the original. I am pasting these versions in false color, to better emphasize artifacts.

[image: original, false colors]

[image: distorted, false colors]

From the images above, you can see color changes in flat/smooth areas, such as the sky above the wire, or the inter-road track orange. So a plausible **background bias**, with at least a relatively low-frequency part: look at the vertical  orange-red-orange transition above the wires, with a period of around $1/3$ of the image width.

The original is jpeg-compressed with a unity quantization table (100% quality), the rescaled and white-bordered was  jpeg-compressed with much lower quality (75%), which you can see from **blocking artifacts** in a 7-pixel frame around the image. You can verify the details, using for instance [JPEGsnoop](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpegsnoop):

> a detailed JPEG image decoder and analysis tool. It reports all image metadata and can even help identify if an image has been edited

Then we can look at gradients:

[image: original, gradient, false colors]

[image: distorted, gradient, false colors]

or Fourier spectrum (average removed, windowed):

[image: original, spectrum, false colors]

[image: distorted, spectrum, false colors]

So, the gradient is noisier, and coarser, and the Fourier spectrum looks similar, only noisier and equalized. 
I doubt about the hypothesis of  a paper scan at a lower resolution. However, the color fluctuation and the stripped-noise patterns reminds me of patterns one can observe when reconstructing image from phase and magnitude (from SE.DSP [Recover image by only magnitude of image fourier transform](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9126/recover-image-by-only-magnitude-of-image-fourier-transform))

[image: magnitude/phase image reconstruction]

So a possibility: the original image was downsampled by a $3/2$ ratio in the Fourier domain, and reconstructed without too much care.

I would be glad to get image expert feedback in this wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

Perlin? Though to me it looks like a poor nearest-neighbor interpolation, after up-down resampling. I'm just replying with a guess, I admit.

Comment: I agree with interpolation error and bad up-down resampling, we can clearly see aliasing on the noisy image. Image has been saved with a bad resolution, then upsampled probably for displaying issues, some informations have been lost and the interpolation after up sampling is bad.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is for sure a poor up-down sampling / interpolation that cause some aliasing. 
I don't know for the wild superimposed texture. My guess would be a bad inverse radon transform, but it is very unlikely in a photography context ... Maybe it is  compression artifact from a ridgelet transform.

[image]

Area 2 is clearer than it should be while right and left side are darker, as if mean along columns had corrupted every rows.

In area 1 we can see line shaped artifacts, it makes me think about radon 
transform stuff.

There is also a clear loss of contrast